# Is there a way to determine if a given point (lat, long) is inside a drawn polygon?

Tags: javascript, function, kml, google-earth, point-in-polygon

I have a KML file with about 5 polygon placemarks and I was wondering if there's a way to determine if a specified point is inside any of the polygons. Does Google Earth have a function to do that or can one be written?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ray casting method for point in polygon test.
The test shoots off a ray towards infinity (arbitrarily chosen direction, usually parallel to one of the axis used for code simplicity and speed) from the test point and counts the intersections with the polygon in question. If the number of intersections are odd, then the point lies within the polygon, else it lies outside. Repeat this test for all the polygons.
check out this link for further explanation and degenerate and special cases.
[pip wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) .
I've implemented this function in C so let me know if you need any pointers.
You could alternatively also use the Winding Number test. [WN wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number)
They may have similar performances depending on the implementation and the platform.
The implementations you'l find may be mostly for Cartesian co-ordinates. Keep in mind that they'l work perfectly fine as it is, with geographic co-ordinates as well.